# I'm having problems with Julia's Plots package, does anyone know how to solve it?

Tags: compiler-errors, julia

Lately when I try to use this package I get this error message:

[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching floatrange(::Type{Float64}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Int64)

Closest candidates are:

floatrange(::Type{T}, ::Integer, ::Integer, ::Integer, ::Integer) where T at twiceprecision.jl:381
floatrange(::AbstractFloat, ::AbstractFloat, ::Real, ::AbstractFloat) at twiceprecision.jl:395
Stacktrace:

Someone knows how fix it?

Comment: Does [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/problem-with-precompiling-plots-in-julia-1-8-2/88235/3) help?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when the Plots.jl package has been downgraded by installation of some other package. This happened to me when I installed Lathe.jl which requires an outdated version of Plots.jl as it's dependences, hence downgrades the existing Plots.jl package.

I'll suggest first check if all the package in your package manager are up to date using the following command:

```
using Pkg; Pkg.status()
```

This will give you the list of packages installed to your package manager. The asterisks corresponding to the packages indicate that newer version are available. You can do hit and trial to see who is the culprit.

Other way might be removing the Plots.jl package and reinstalling again using the following command:

```
using Pkg; Pkg.rm("Plots")
```

or

```
using Pkg; Pkg.remove("Plots")
```

then,

```
using Pkg; Pkg.add("Plots")
```

Other that I don't suggest but can be tried is to take note of your packages, uninstall julia, delete all the .julia folder in your file explorer and reinstall julia and as you install the packages you require, look closely at the dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Any packages with newer versions available? More specifically, is Plots.jl has an asterisk next to it?